# C# String new line

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, string

I have an ASPX page within my web application, I'm trying to create a string with multiple lines within a string and use it for this method

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + Message + "');", true);
```

This code is in the .cs file.

I tried multiple ways to create this string as multi lines but it seems it doesnt work, I have used methods like:

```
String Message = "Not Authorised to use Sysomos. "+ "<br>" + " Please Email Ian Atkinson for Authorisation";

String Message = "Not Authorised to use Sysomos. "+ Enviroment.NewLine + " Please Email Ian Atkinson for Authorisation";
```

Both these methods do not work. I have also tried a string builder and no luck.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
String Message = "Not Authorised to use Sysomos. \\n Please Email Ian Atkinson for Authorisation";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `\n` character for `n`ew lines

```
alert("Hello \n \n World!");
```